# search in whole binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a method which prints the title of the movie if it matches the year from the parameter.

```
private void searchByYear(BTNode root, int year) {
    BTNode temp = root;
    if(temp == null)
        return;
    else if(temp.data.titleYear == year){
        System.out.println(temp.data.title);
    }
    else{
        searchByYear(temp.left, year);
        searchByYear(temp.right, year);
    }
}
```

Problem: It prints some movies, not all. I believe the problme should be in the recursive call.

Note: The sorting is not on the basis of year, so I have to search from the whole tree. Also I want the method to print, not to return node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the `else if` block with the `else` block so that it makes the recursive call after performing the check.

```
private void searchByYear(BTNode root, int year) {
    BTNode temp = root;
    if(temp == null)
        return;
    if(temp.data.titleYear == year){
        System.out.println(temp.data.title);
    }

    searchByYear(temp.left, year);
    searchByYear(temp.right, year);
 }
```

Comment: And for **in-order printing** the left-search should happen before the year if.

Comment: wouldn't this recur even when we have found the data we need?

Comment: I think he wants to print every movie made that year

Comment: Thanks for this, " so that it makes the recursive call after performing the check."

Comment: ohh sorry about that. I think I need a break!!

Comment: @user7 Doing `searchByYear(temp.left, year); if ...; searchByYear(temp.right, year);` would call printlns in the same order as a sorted (?) binary tree. (I upvoted)

Comment: @JoopEggen Oh ya. But the OP didn't need it anyway I guess (anyway we just need to search for one year)

Comment: If the tree would be sorted by title, then the result would be all titles of that year, nicely sorted too. But really my comment was just intended as a tiny improvement, maybe even irrelevant here.